# Problem with Raise Dead?

Tags: dnd-4e

My four players have decided on the following plan: once a week, they all cut off three pieces of their hair and give it the others. This way, if another character is ever killed, they can pull out the hair to resurrect them. They will use the Raise Dead ritual since they only need an unspecified part of the player to be able to resurrect them.

I really really dislike this gamey way of playing, but I could find no reason why this would be against the rules.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hair isn't really "part" of a corpse, if that's all you have. I don't have dust bunnies composed of human corpses under my couch, right? Make it require flesh and then see how long this strategy lasts...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by preventing this?

Comment: Here's a thought: introduce another side to this. A *hazard* of just having tufts of your hair in easy-to-pickpocket places, to go along with the benefit they've discovered. An evil necromancer could be on the lookout for new minions to control, and the ritual involves the same kind of "part" of someone's body as the raise dead ritual. There's all sorts of superstitions about leaving parts of yourself around, be it hair, nails, or teeth, so this isn't a far-fetched scenario for fantasy a RPG.

Comment: It looks like both mine and @SevenSidedDie's thoughts have been pre-empted in [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5066/6104) and others to [Clarification on 4e Raise Dead's 'part of the corpse'](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5030/6104).

Comment: @detly Corpse Gate specifies "at least the tip of a finger". Does Raise Dead do similar? I don't have erratad books.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The compendium doesn't say anything like that, and I presume the errata are factored in to that. But there's also the issue of whether "part of the corpse" means: "must come from the actual, dead, corpse and not the living character."

Comment: @detly That question/ritual don't specify that it must, only that if the target is *currently* anything other than normal-dead the ritual fails. It could be a tooth taken from a living human, later vampirised, later killed and purified (or whatever) and it would work.

Comment: My question is a duplicate of the one detly linked to, which is why I'm going to delete it. Sorry for not doing my research properly, I completely missed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Part of a corpse" is the crucial language here. A corpse, by definition, is a dead body. When they cut their hair off every week they are not taking a part of a corpse. They are taking a part of a living body. So that part cannot be used later for Raise Dead. They have to be a corpse before the part of the corpse can be taken for use in the ritual.

Comment: Yes, you don’t necessarily tell the players this until they try casting it. Then panic ensues haha

Answer (score 11):

As GM, clearly it is up to you to dictate what constitutes "part of a corpse". Maybe a tuft of hair is alright. One could reasonably argue that at least some amount of flesh is required, or at least some percentage of original body weight, and so on.

However I believe the real issue is not with the mechanics at all, but with the way the players are approaching the situation. You feel that they are somehow 'cheating the system'. Personally I think they're just getting into the spirit of the game. That they felt the need to plan ahead might be indicative of your GMing style. Why do they feel that way? Is the campaign excessively dangerous? That they **did** plan ahead should be rewarded. Trying to account for a more difficult campaign only to have their plans foiled will make for frustrated players.

Finally, there is certainly not a balance concern with this. Are you routinely dissolving your PCs in acid, or disintegrating them into dust? If they actually get annihilated to the point of no return, **of course** they are looking for smart ways to prevent it. I assume (and sincerely hope) that this is not the case, so really in the end it makes no meaningful difference.

Comment: +1 for rewarding the players for planning ahead, not punishing them. Though I would personally require more than just a lock of hair. A finger, maybe… *big evil grin*

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker I agree, a lock of hair is pushing it. That being said, there is still no game mechanical difference between the two. There is certainly an RP difference though.

Comment: Of course, if hair isn't enough, their _characters_ don't really have the GM telling them, so they may be in for a rough surprise further down the line, unless they get some in-game professional advice.

Comment: It's 4.0, so no, it hasn't been deadly. The players are epic tier and they've had exactly 1 death during the entire 3-year campaign (which was more or less coordinated between myself and the player in question). However, they're attempting to defuse two linked bombs and expect one of them to go off and annihilate whoever is attempting to disarm it.